# Oracle VirtualBox Manager settings change after doing "vagrant up"

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, memory, cpu, vagrant

I changed memory and processor settings in Oracle VirtualBox Manager but when I do `vagrant up` to activate my environment, the settings change back to default. I made sure to power off the virtual box before I change the settings and the problem is still there. Here are the settings before and after:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgLeC.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVr22.png)

Memory and CPU are maxed out so it slows down my computer like crazy. This only happens with one of my virtual boxes. It doesn't happen normally.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The memory and cpu limit were defined in vagrant file so the values in the file were overriding the Virtualbox Manager.